# Use DateDiff function to match two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I have the following check:

```
'20'+convert(char,tc.TransactionDateStamp,12) = pr.DateOut
AND substring(tc.TransactionTimeStamp,1,2) + substring(tc.TransactionTimeStamp,4,2) + substring(tc.TransactionTimeStamp,7,2) = pr.TimeOut
```

This works, but if the time in `tc.TransactionTimeStamp` is different to `pr.TimeOut` by like five seconds then it doesnt match. I need to put in a check which will allow these two to match even if the time is diff by 30 seconds.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of `tc.TransactionDateStamp` content, and a sample of `tc.TransactionTimeStamp` content?

Comment: Are you really storing date/time values using strings?  Or are you inappropriately using string functions on date/time values?

Answer (score 1):

Is this?

```
'20'+convert(char,tc.TransactionDateStamp,12) = pr.DateOut 
AND substring(tc.TransactionTimeStamp,1,2)+substring
(tc.TransactionTimeStamp,4,2)+substring
(tc.TransactionTimeStamp,7,2) between pr.TimeOut and pr.TimeOut+30
```

Comment: ok, but have seen now a problem that if the time in the TransactionTimestamp is higher then the time in TimeOut then this does not work as it only works if the Timeout is same or up to 30 seconds more then transactiontimestamp